# Использование английского или транслита в ЧПУ

Tags: seo, чпу

Не могу найти информацию об использовании транслитерации в URL. Чем `/informaciya/soglashenie/` лучше чем `/information/agreement/`? Важно ли это для ранжирования поисковыми машинами и, если да, то на сколько важно? Есть ли какие-то конкретные правила транслитерации? Может у самих поисковиков есть документация которую я не смог найти. Нужна любая информация по этому вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часто урл генерируется автоматически, а написать транслитерацию гораздо проще чем переводчик. В результате получается "soglashenie". Это немного лучше чем "соглашение", потому что при копировании ссылка не превратится в "%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5". Но "soglashenie" хуже чем "agreement", потому что транслитерация в названии документа – это дурной тон.

|  | русский | translit | english |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| понятнее нашей аудитории | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| понятнее иностранцам | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| проблема при копировании | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| круто выглядит | 1 | 0 | 1 |

[Правила транслитерации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9) есть и их несколько. Для ЧПУ программисты просто берут любую доступную готовую реализацию.

Теоретически поисковики могут увеличивать вес ссылки, содержащей ключевые слова в урле. При этом они, скорее всего, справятся и с кириллицей, и с транслитерацией и с переводом. Но вряд ли это то, на что надо делать упор. Поисковики стремятся предложить пользователям релевантную информацию и для этого есть гораздо более эффективные методы, чем поиск ключевых слов в урле.

Если вас беспокоит ранжирование, то сосредоточьте свои усилия на том, чтобы сайт был полезен, удобен и безопасен для пользователей. Играйте на стороне поисковика, не пытайтесь его одурачить. А если вам нужна реклама, то просто купите её.

Посмотрите как делают крутые ребята:

- Для [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F) важно, чтобы пользователь видел название в урле на родном языке;
- [Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/company/museum/logo) не может себе позволить урл типа "o_kompanii";
- [Хабр](https://habr.com/ru/post/469139/) не даёт пользователям управлять урлами и все посты просто нумеруются (обратите внимание, что это не мешает находить их в гугле).

Comment: Про игру на стороне поисковика это понятно. У продукта настал момент когда нужно решить как будут оформляться url и нужно взвесить все за и против, а информации от самих поисковиков очень мало. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Дурной тон - это нести ересь про дурной тон транслитерации.

Comment: @SeVlad я говорил только про названия документов. Например имена транслитерировать это нормально. Но странно называть страницу "domashnyaya_stranica", когда можно назвать "homepage" или "домашняя страница".